# Extending Laravel's default routes.php

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

laravel 5 's routes.php contains this code

```
Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

i have arranged my code in modules folder so every module has its own folder with controller and everything with a separate routes.php , i have created a custom module named Auth inside my modules folder , and it's routes.php content is

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 
'namespace' => 'Modules\Auth\Http\Controllers'], function ()
{
    Route::get('login', 'AuthController@index');
});
```

now when i try to access example.com/auth/login my custom route do not get called , due to routes defined inside laravel's default routes.php  ,how can i make my route work without touching laravel's routes.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespace is correct, and is matching up to your folder structure. 
also consider adding the full path to the controller you would like to use. hope this helps, not enough code above to really see what you have implemented thus far :)